# .NET application memory usage concerning private bytes vs peak private bytes

Tags: .net, memory-leaks

I am testing a long running .NET application which interacts with an unmanaged DLL and am using ProcessExplorer to monitor its memory usage.

Private Bytes does not increase and stays around 21-25MB but I get a huge increase in Peak Private Bytes ~ 242MB

What does Peak Private Bytes indicate? that the application needed that amount memory sometime during processing for its own requirements or am I experiencing a memory leak?

I should also mention that Virtual Size is about 160MB

Comment: That's entirely normal for a non-trivial .NET app.  A garbage collector likes virtual memory.  It is virtual, it doesn't cost anything.  You are still a good factor of 6 away from running out of address space, there is no problem here.

Comment: I am sorry I meant "but I get a huge increase in Peak Private Bytes " not "but I get a huge increase in Peak Virtual Bytes" as it orginally standed.I've re-edited the question. Would that make any diference in your answer ?

Comment: It doesn't, private bytes are just bytes that you don't share with another process.  Which is entirely normal, the garbage collected heap isn't shared.